# xslt: selecting between following nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<division>
    <subdiv id="1" type="author">
        <emptype value="1"/>
        <p>name of author</p>
        <p>date</p>
    </subdiv>
    <subdiv id="2" type="acknowledgement">
        <emptype value="2"/>
        <h>acknowledgement</h>
        <p>some texts</p>
        <emptype value="3"/>
        <p>more text</p>
    </subdiv>
    <subdiv id="3" type="chapters">
        <emptype value="4"/>
        <emptype value="5"/>
        <emptype value="6"/>
        <h>chapter 1</h>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        <p>paragraph 3</p>
        <emptype value="7"/>
        <p>paragraph 4</p>
        <emptype value="8"/>
        <h>chapter 2</h>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
     </subdiv>
</division>
```

I am splitting this XSLT into separate files for each `<subdiv>` node.  If any `<subdiv>` node contains an `<emptype>` node that occurs before the first `<h>` node, that `<emptype>` node should be moved to the previous `<subdiv>` node instead.

e.g.

**file1**

```
<division>
    <subdiv id="1" type="author">
        <emptype value="1"/>
        <p>name of author</p>
        <p>date</p>
        <emptype value="2"/>
    </subdiv>
</division>
```

**file2**

```
<division>
    <subdiv id="2" type="acknowledgement">
        <h>acknowledgement</h>
        <p>some texts</p>
        <emptype value="3"/>
        <p>more text</p>
        <emptype value="4"/>
        <emptype value="5"/>
        <emptype value="6"/>
     </subdiv>
</division>
```

**file3**

```
<division>
    <subdiv id="3" type="chapters">
        <h>chapter 1</h>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        <p>paragraph 3</p>
        <emptype value="7"/>
        <p>paragraph 4</p>
        <emptype value="8"/>
        <h>chapter 2</h>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
     </subdiv>
</division>
```

I am able to split the XML into separate files, but unable move the `<emptype>` nodes to the proper place. I would appreciate any help.

***NOTE***: I am only looking only for the XPath expression to select the `<emptype>` nodes that are inside a `<subdiv>` but before the first occurrence of `<h>`.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the XSLT you've got so far.  Indent preformatted code blocks by four spaces (you can use the `{}` button) to get them to appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is the XPath expression, the following should work:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="subdiv/emptype[count(preceding-sibling::h) = 0 and count(../h) &gt; 0]" />
```

This will copy an `<emptype>` node only if it doesn't have any preceding siblings called `<h>`, and there is at least one sibling called `<h>`.  (The second condition allows for the `<emptype value="1">` to be copied, which it appears that you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to get the emptypes from the next subdiv?

Assuming the subdiv is your current context node:

```
following-sibling::subdiv[1]/emptype[not(preceding-sibling::h)]
```

This does not take into account how to handle the final subdiv.  I would use an xsl:if test against last() rather than try to get confusingly tricky with the XPath.

Comment: Thanks a lot. phew. Was copying from current context subdiv . There are no emptype tags after final subdiv. I am using xsl:if to check if there following emptype